# sed: how to insert a comment at the beginning of a matching line

Tags: bash, scripting, sed

I am attempting to write a script that will comment out the following line in /etc/sudoers every time I launch a new EC2 instance:

`Defaults    requiretty`

I'm assuming the best way to do this is with an inline sed search and replace or search and insert. The issue is there could be 1+ spaces/tabs between Defaults and requiretty also. What's an efficient sed solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jay's answer will work almost unchanged with `sed`:

```
sed -i 's/^Defaults[ \t]+requiretty/# Defaults requiretty/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd use Perl, personally

```
perl -pi -e 's/(^Defaults\s+requiretty)/# $1/g' /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

(Line must start with `Defaults` to match it. If you don't want that, just remove the `^`. The `\s+` will catch any number of spaces between `Defaults` and `requiretty`.)

Comment: You can remove the code dup with () and $1

Comment: Excellent point, thanks. I have revised the answer accordingly.